# Couchbase N1QL update query for Array of objects

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

I am new to n1ql. I want to search all records in a bucket with "**ABC**" and replace it with "**DEF**". Can you please help me in creating this query and index?
Sample records

```
{
  "userTypeNm": "pro",
  "userStateArray": [
    {
      "bindCd": "1591779772457",
      "name": "########",
      "state": "**ABC**",
      "ts": "1591779772457"
    }
  ],
  "vts": "1591779772457",
  "ets": "1591779772457",
  "daoObj": {
    "authDaObj": {
      "data": "eyJ0cmFuc2FjdGlvbklkIjoiVVNMT0dPTi0xN2U3YWQ5ZC0wN",
      "id": "829892839892"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default
 (DISTINCT ARRAY v.state FOR v IN userStateArray END) WHERE userTypeNm = "pro";

UPDATE default  AS d  SET usa.state = "DEF"  FOR usa IN d.userStateArray WHEN usa.state = "ABC" END
WHERE ANY v IN d.userStateArray SATISFIES v.state = "ABC" END;
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html